# Create Bootstrap Layout with panel on left and right side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

Trying to create this layout:

[image]

...but having difficulty with having a panel on the left and right that way.

Hoping someone can help. Here is what I have so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/o1g39soq/

```
<div class="row flex-row">
<div class="panel panel-default flex-col">
<div class="panel-heading">Title flex-col</div>
<div class="panel-body flex-grow" style="height: 20%">
  <div class="row seven-cols flex-row">
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="panel panel-default no-margin flex-col">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title flex-col</div>
        <div class="panel-body flex-grow">Content here -- div with .flex-grow</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="panel panel-default no-margin flex-col">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title flex-col</div>
        <div class="panel-body flex-grow">Content here -- div with .flex-grow</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="panel panel-default no-margin flex-col">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title flex-col</div>
        <div class="panel-body flex-grow">Content here -- div with .flex-grow</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="panel panel-default no-margin flex-col">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title flex-col</div>
        <div class="panel-body flex-grow">Content here -- div with .flex-grow</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="panel panel-default no-margin flex-col">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title flex-col</div>
        <div class="panel-body flex-grow">Content here -- div with .flex-grow</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="panel-body flex-grow" style="max-height:30px; background-color: #f5f5f5">
</div>

<div class="panel-body flex-grow">
  <div class="row seven-cols flex-row">
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="panel panel-default flex-col">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title flex-col</div>
        <div class="panel-body flex-grow">Content here -- div with .flex-grow</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="panel panel-default flex-col">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title flex-col</div>
        <div class="panel-body flex-grow">Content here -- div with .flex-grow</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="panel panel-default flex-col">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title flex-col</div>
        <div class="panel-body flex-grow">Content here -- div with .flex-grow</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="panel panel-default flex-col">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title flex-col</div>
        <div class="panel-body flex-grow">Content here -- div with .flex-grow</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="panel panel-default flex-col">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title flex-col</div>
        <div class="panel-body flex-grow">Content here -- div with .flex-grow</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="panel panel-default flex-col">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title flex-col</div>
        <div class="panel-body flex-grow">Content here -- div with .flex-grow</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="panel panel-default flex-col">
        <div class="panel-heading">Title flex-col</div>
        <div class="panel-body flex-grow">Content here -- div with .flex-grow</div>
        <div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
<div class="panel-footer">Footer</div>
```

Here is the css.

```
    html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container,
.row {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-row,
.flex-row > div[class*='col-'] {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
}

.flex-col {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

.flex-grow {
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex: 2;
  flex: 2;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .seven-cols .col-md-1,
  .seven-cols .col-sm-1,
  .seven-cols .col-lg-1 {
    width: 100%;
    *width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .seven-cols .col-md-1,
  .seven-cols .col-sm-1,
  .seven-cols .col-lg-1 {
    width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;
    *width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;
  }
}


/**
 *  The following is not really needed in this case
 *  Only to demonstrate the usage of @media for large screens
 */

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .seven-cols .col-md-1,
  .seven-cols .col-sm-1,
  .seven-cols .col-lg-1 {
    width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;
    *width: 14.285714285714285714285714285714%;
  }
}

.panel-body {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
}

.no-margin {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try `position: relative;` and `top: -50%;`
Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o1g39soq/1/)
Added `left` and `right` classes, see HTML lines 54 and 97 and CSS line 38

Comment: ...on what? you just copied and pasted my fiddle link.

Comment: expand the result frame to see the difference

Comment: really sorry, but I'm not seeing any visual changes. I see the stuff you added based on the line numbers but nothing in the results.

Comment: Oh it works, but in Edge, not in Chrome...do you know why that may be?

Comment: I'm using Chrome. Try [updating](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/) it

Comment: I'm using Chrome Canary. Didn't work in normal Chrome for me too

Comment: strange, its okay. thank you for your help tho :D mind if I ask you one more question that you may or may not know why it's happening? ( I made a similar layout in a different way...and it looks fine on my monitor...but if I move it to a different resolution...everything looks zoomed in and overlapping so I need to zoom out or in for it to look normal again..do you know why or how I can fix it?)

Comment: Adding `overflow: hidden;`(not sure to which, I added it to everything) disables words from coming out, but the div's are designed to be responsive so the middle part changes size. I don't know bootstrap, so I cant help you. Sorry